# kth smallest element out of an non-unique sorted array

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic

This is probably a Microsoft interview question.

Find the kth smallest element (ignoring duplicates) out of an sorted array.
**[EDIT]**: The array may contain duplicates(not specified).

Thought a bunch of times, but still questioning myself: **Does there still exist a better solution?**

### Approach 1:

Take a max heap & insert first k unique elements[can be easily checked]. Heapify the heap.
Now, when a new element is smaller than the head of the heap,replace head with this new element  heapify it. At the last, the head of the heap indicates kth smallest element if size of the heap is k else kth smallest element doesn't exist.

Time complexity: O(NlogK)
Space complexity: O(K)

### Approach 2[A better approach]:

The elements may be duplicated right. So, check for unique elements by comparing with its previous elements & stop if unique variables found so far counts to k.
Time complexity: O(N)
Space complexity: O(1)

### Approach 3[A better approach(may be)]:

A modified version of quick sort partition algorithm can also be used. But possibly it will lead to a worst case as the array is already sorted.
here two questions arise:
1. **Does it work if the array contain duplicates?**
2. **Would it be better than my second apporach?**

---

I was wondering that **does there exist any O(logn) solution?**

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't the "k-th smallest element of an sorted array" is just the k-th element of the array? The array is *sorted*...

Comment: if the array is sorted, why not take the element at k-th position?

Comment: @KennyTM  .. Aint that easy.. It can hav duplicates..

Comment: KennyTM, FlopCoder: {1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6}. Your algorithm incorrectly returns 1 for k = 3.

Comment: @Bragboy, ngmiceli: You didn't mention "unique elements" :) The default interpretation is to include duplicates, e.g. [C++ says 1 is the correct answer for the 3rd smallest element](http://ideone.com/nPoCF).

Comment: @KennyTM: The c++ standard is careful about phrasing though -- it describes `nth_element` in terms of which element would end up at that spot if the array were fully sorted. Since this array is fully sorted, using k as the index into the array clearly works for what it says it'll do.

Comment: You can make the lookup O(1) by keeping a separate sorted collection of just the unique values.  You would just be adding more to the space cost and insert/delete cost.  However, this could be preferable if you do lots more "kth smallest" lookups than inserts/deletes.

Comment: In *Approach 1*, the last value entered *is* the result required - rather than continue, give details about `first k unique elements[can be easily checked]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an O(kLogN) solution:

Using a variation of Binary Search to find the last occurrence of a given value,

1. Get 1st value - O(1).
2. Search for last occurrence of this value O(logN), then look at next element to get 2nd value - O(1).
3. Repeat until kth value is found.

Comment: This is not better than O(n) which is same as O(k)

Comment: +1 - This is a great answer is certainly it is what the interviewer was looking for.  It should be noted, though, that for some values of _k_ and _n_, it is slower than the O(n) solution.

Comment: @amit.codename13, generally, yes, but that's another option, which will work much better for a variety of inputs.

Comment: Given that the value of k has an upperbound of N, I agree with @amit.codename13 in that this is O(N logN) and in the worst case just comparing the values in place would be O(N). That said, this is an interview question. They want you to come up with these kinds of out-of-the-box solutions. And for very large N and relatively small k there is a real world performance gain. That said, If I was actually paying someone to do this (not testing their abilities) I'd definitely raise my eyebrow that they didn't just scan the list in O(N) time.

Comment: @acattle - If this was for a real project, I'd wonder why someone didn't build a separate index of unique values, allowing for O(1) lookup.

Answer (score 5):

There appear to be two different interpretations of *k*-th smallest element.  I am assuming it means "the *k*-th smallest element, ignoring duplicates."

The best solution is O(n) time and O(1) space, as you describe in approach 2.  We can prove this.

- We cannot improve upon O(1) space (at least not in O-notation).
- Consider an approach that runs in less than O(n).  Such an approach must not consider each element in the array.  Consider one such missed element.  It it not known if this element is or is not a duplicate of the value previous to it or after it¹, and this information is required for asserting which value in the array corresponds to the *k*-th smallest.

¹ It is possible to infer the values of a arbitrarily long subsequence of a sorted array in the special case that two non-adjacent array elements have the same value: all of the interim elements must share that value.  But this is not a typical case, so I'm ignoring it.

Comment: the second statement contains a fallacy. That's exactly the only possible point of such a problem is that we should try hard to skip analysing  those lengthy sequences of equal numbers.

Comment: I mean, what if majority of the array is filled with 5s and the algorithm magically skips all the 5s surrounded by other 5s, the second statement doesn't show any contradiction.

Comment: @unkulunkulu You are right that that is the only point of the problem.  However, since we are not guaranteed our input data contains duplicates, we cannot make guarantees about the runtime based on optimizations that depend upon their presence.

Comment: check my second comment, your statement doesn't show contradiction for the case when all the skipped elements are in segments of equality. I support your idea that there's no general solution that is always better than `O(n)` (there *is* a solution that is better than `O(n)` for special class of inputs though), I'm just saying your proof looks wrong to me.

Comment: @unkulunkulu I agree it doesn't demonstrate a contradiction in that case (which is why I made a footnote stating that I'm ignoring that case).  Apologies if things are unclear.

Comment: yeah, I didn't get it about the footnote, sorry, but then I don't understand what your statement is about. It says something like 'there is no better algorithm than O(n) if the input sequence contains no longer than two consecutive elements that are equal'. Don't see how it answers the question that specifically is about the general case or even the opposite.

Comment: @unkulunkulu In summary, my answer was attempting to say: "Given arbitrary input, there is no algorithm that guarantees better speed than O(n)."

Comment: @cheeken - You need to qualify that further. If you allow more space to be used, and more time on inserts/deletes, then you can achieve O(1) finding of k-th smallest element.

Comment: @mbeckish The question is not how to create a data structure that will allow you to access the _k_-th smallest element, so inserts/deletes are not relevant (unless I'm misunderstanding you).  The question has to do with being given an arbitrary array and finding a particular element.  We cannot assume that array conforms to a particular data structure.

Comment: @cheeken - I'm not saying the given array needs to be the index - I'm suggesting creating a second data structure, using the data in the given array.  If you didn't allow for that, then there is no need to talk about the space complexity of the solution.